# ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/acts_as_paranoid-0.3.1/lib/acts_as_paranoid.rb:42:in `alias_method'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, acts-as-paranoid

I am trying to use acts_as_paranoid gem, is already added in Gemfile (gem 'acts_as_paranoid') bundle updated and installed Installing acts_as_paranoid (0.3.1) 
but when I start my server I have the following error, any ideas? Thank you very much!

```
/Users/jcr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /Users/jcr/web/sss/bin/rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -e development

/Users/jcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/acts_as_paranoid-0.3.1/lib/acts_as_paranoid.rb:42:in `alias_method': undefined method `validate_find_options' for class `Class' (NameError)
    from /Users/jcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/acts_as_paranoid-0.3.1/lib/acts_as_paranoid.rb:42:in `singletonclass'
    from /Users/jcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/acts_as_paranoid-0.3.1/lib/acts_as_paranoid.rb:41:in `included'
    from /Users/jcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/acts_as_paranoid-0.3.1/lib/acts_as_paranoid.rb:166:in `include'
    from /Users/jcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/acts_as_paranoid-0.3.1/lib/acts_as_paranoid.rb:166:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
    from /Users/jcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/jcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
    from /Users/jcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
    from /Users/jcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
    from /Users/jcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
    from /Users/jcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /Users/jcr/web/sss/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `require'
    from /Users/jcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/jcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
    from /Users/jcr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jcr/web/sss/bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from /Users/jcr/web/sss/bin/rails:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: What is the rails version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That gem looks dead, I think the `validate_find_options` method is removed in Rails 4.

Looks like [Paranoia](https://github.com/radar/paranoia) is the current replacement.